# Strip out spaces in EXIF file (.txt file) with Python

Tags: python, dictionary, gps, exif, exiftool

I have .txt files (one per image) that is formatted as can be seen below. I cannot figure out how to extract the information, without spaces, I am interested in.

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.20
File Name                       : R0010023.tiff
Directory                       : C:/gtag/wf1313
File Size                       : 46 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2016:07:07 20:57:38+01:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2016:07:07 20:57:38+01:00
File Creation Date/Time         : 2016:07:04 21:18:17+01:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-rw-
File Type                       : TIFF
File Type Extension             : tif
MIME Type                       : image/tiff
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Image Width                     : 4928
Image Height                    : 3264
Bits Per Sample                 : 8 8 8
Compression                     : PackBits
Photometric Interpretation      : RGB
Image Description               : 
Make                            : RICOH IMAGING COMPANY, LTD.
Camera Model Name               : GR II
Strip Offsets                   : (Binary data 558 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
Samples Per Pixel               : 3
Rows Per Strip                  : 51
Strip Byte Counts               : (Binary data 447 bytes, use -b option to extract)
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Planar Configuration            : Chunky
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Software                        : GR Firmware Ver 01.02
Modify Date                     : 2016:06:21 13:09:52
XMP Toolkit                     : Image::ExifTool 10.20
Compressed Bits Per Pixel       : 3.2
Flash Fired                     : False
Flash Function                  : False
Flash Red Eye Mode              : False
Flash Return                    : No return detection
Interoperability Index          : R98 - DCF basic file (sRGB)
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Centered
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Copyright                       : 
Exposure Time                   : 1/1250
F Number                        : 6.3
ISO                             : 100
Sensitivity Type                : Standard Output Sensitivity
Exif Version                    : 0230
Date/Time Original              : 2016:06:21 13:09:52
Create Date                     : 2016:06:21 13:09:52
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Aperture Value                  : 6.3
Brightness Value                : 8.6
Exposure Compensation           : 0
Max Aperture Value              : 2.8
Metering Mode                   : Multi-segment
Light Source                    : Shade
Maker Note Type                 : Rdc
Firmware Version                : 1.02
Recording Format                : JPEG
Exposure Program                : Manual
Drive Mode                      : Single-frame
White Balance                   : Shade
White Balance Fine Tune         : 0 0
Focus Mode                      : Manual
Auto Bracketing                 : Off
Macro Mode                      : Off
Flash Mode                      : Off
Flash Exposure Comp             : 0
Manual Flash Output             : Full
Full Press Snap                 : Off
Dynamic Range Expansion         : Off
Noise Reduction                 : Weak
Image Effects                   : Standard
Vignetting                      : Off
Toning Effect                   : Off
Hue Adjust                      : Off
Focal Length                    : 18.3 mm
AF Area X Position 1            : 632
AF Area Y Position 1            : 418
AF Area X Position              : 2435
AF Area Y Position              : 1610
AF Status                       : In Focus
AF Area Mode                    : Auto
Sensor Width                    : 4928
Sensor Height                   : 3264
Cropped Image Width             : 4928
Cropped Image Height            : 3264
Wide Adapter                    : Not Attached
Color Temp Kelvin               : 0
Crop Mode 35mm                  : Off
ND Filter                       : Off
WB Bracket Shot Number          : 0
User Comment                    : 
Flashpix Version                : 0100
Color Space                     : sRGB
Exif Image Width                : 4928
Exif Image Height               : 3264
Exposure Mode                   : Manual
Focal Length In 35mm Format     : 28 mm
Scene Capture Type              : Standard
Contrast                        : Normal
Saturation                      : Normal
Sharpness                       : Normal
Owner Name                      : 
Serial Number                   : (00000000)14100511
Lens Info                       : 18.3mm f/2.8
Lens Make                       : RICOH IMAGING COMPANY, LTD.
Lens Model                      : GR LENS
GPS Version ID                  : 2.3.0.0
GPS Latitude Ref                : xxxx
GPS Longitude Ref               : xxxx
GPS Altitude Ref                : Above Sea Level
GPS Time Stamp                  : 12:09:52
GPS Img Direction Ref           : True North
GPS Img Direction               : 228.21
GPS Date Stamp                  : 2016:06:21
GPS Pitch                       : 0.79
GPS Roll                        : 0.41
PrintIM Version                 : 0300
Aperture                        : 6.3
Flash                           : Off, Did not fire
GPS Altitude                    : 91.7 m Above Sea Level
GPS Date/Time                   : 2016:06:21 12:09:52Z
GPS Latitude                    : xx deg xx' x.xx" N
GPS Longitude                   : x deg x' xx.xx" W
GPS Position                    : xx deg xx' x.xx" N, x deg x' xx.xx" W
Image Size                      : 4928x3264
Megapixels                      : 16.1
Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent: 1.5
Shutter Speed                   : 1/1250
Circle Of Confusion             : 0.020 mm
Field Of View                   : 65.5 deg
Focal Length                    : 18.3 mm (35 mm equivalent: 28.0 mm)
Hyperfocal Distance             : 2.71 m
Light Value                     : 15.6
```

I have the following code,

```
import glob
file_list = glob.glob("*.txt")

for file_ in file_list:
    saved_lines = []
    sfile = open(file_, "r")
    lines = sfile.readlines() #array of all lines
    for line in lines:
        for text in ['File Name', 'GPS Longitude', 'GPS Latitude', 'GPS Altitude', 'GPS Img Direction', 'GPS Pitch', 'GPS Roll']:
            if text in line:
                saved_lines.append(line)
    parsed = "".join(saved_lines) #reassemble the file
    with open("parsed.txt", "a") as ofile: #write your output
        ofile.write(parsed)

dict={}
sfile = open("R001.txt", "r")
list = sfile.readlines()
for i in list:
    dict[i.split(':')[0]] = ''.join(i.split(':')[1:])
```

The challenge I am facing is that I need to format the data in the following format (to be able to import it in a program I would like to use),

```
"#image latitude    longitude   altitude    yaw pitch   roll"
"R001.JPG   xx.xxxx x.xxxx  xxx.xx  319.9   8.2 -2.1"
"R002.JPG   xx.xxxx x.xxxx  xxx.xx  319.4   10.1    3.6"
```

So one line per image with the data above.

Creating a dictionary as above is a good first step (I think). The dictionary is difficult to call, though, as each member of the dictionary has a different number of spaces after the member name. That is, File Name-----------------------:... etcetera.

Is there a way to look up a member, excluding the spaces? I have tried the command `strip()` but that does not work well due to the `:`.

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a name of a variable, you are now masking the built-in type. You don't need to use `lines = fileobj.readlines()`, then loop over that, as you can just loop over the file *itself*: `for line in fileobj:`.

Comment: Thank you! I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just have Exiftool output the info you want in the format you want directly.  If the separator between the each piece of data is a tab (which it sort of looks like it might be), you can just specify the tags you want and the [-T](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#t) option:
`exif -T -FileName -GPSLongitude -GPSLatitude -GPSAltitude -GPSImgDirection -GPSPitch -GPSRoll FileOrDir >Output.txt`

For more control over the output, look into the [-p](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#str) option.

*Edit:*  Here is a sample printformat file that would have output close to your example output

```
#[HEAD]"#image latitude    longitude   altitude    yaw pitch   roll"
"$FileName  $GPSLongitude   $GPSLatitude    $GPSAltitude    $GPSImgDirection    $GPSPitch   $GPSRoll"
```

*Edit 2:*  I used a command like this (Format.Txt contained just the text from my first edit)
`exiftool.exe -p /path/to/Format.txt /Target/DirOrFiles`
And my output looked like this (No pitch or roll because they are non-standard and I don't have them in my config file):

```
"#image latitude    longitude   altitude    yaw pitch   roll"
"0615090217.jpg 116 deg 4' 22.08" W 35 deg 15' 59.37" N 286.9 m Above Sea Level 41.26       "
"20151212-12.12.12.jpg  68 deg 14' 4.56" W  12 deg 7' 2.60" N   286.9 m Above Sea Level 650     "
"DSC_0428test.jpg   82 deg 50' 11.97" W 34 deg 40' 35.21" N             "
"IMGP0713-XL.jpg    156 deg 34' 48.00" W    70 deg 19' 12.00" N             "
"IMG_1279.MOV   84 deg 36' 34.56" W 39 deg 15' 7.92" N  263.716 m           "
"Plugh.jpg  116 deg 4' 22.08" W 35 deg 15' 59.37" N 286.9 m Above Sea Level 41.26       "
"Test5.jpg  116 deg 4' 22.07" W 35 deg 15' 59.37" N 286.9 m Above Sea Level 41.26       "
"xyzzy.jpg  68 deg 14' 4.56" W  12 deg 7' 2.60" N   286.9 m Above Sea Level 650     "
```

Comment: Wow, ExifTool is packed with features. Thank you for this!

Would you happen to know how to write each image as a new line?

I read _Use $$ to represent a $ symbol, and $/ for a newline._ but did not figure out where to add that '$/'.

I tried a range of variations to the following,

#[HEAD]"#$/ image latitude    longitude   altitude    yaw pitch   roll $/"
"$/ $FileName  $GPSLongitude   $GPSLatitude    $GPSAltitude    $GPSImgDirection    $GPSPitch   $GPSRoll $/"

Regards
Joel

Comment: If you use a separate file to hold the format, you don't need to use $/, just use a new line.  Each file will get a separate line, so if you use a command like this:   
`exiftool.exe -p /path/to/Format.txt /Target/DirOrFiles`
Your output will take all the files in the target Dir and give them each a line.  I'll edit my original text with an example.

Comment: Thank you for this. I did not get it to work exactly like it did for you, but to manually add a line break where there should be one does not bother me too much. So, thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 0):

You have several options; the top two would be:

- split a line on `:`, *then* strip the parts:

  ```
  name, value = line.split(':', 1)
  name, value = name.strip(), value.strip()
  ```

  Note the second argument to `str.split()` as well; this limits the number of times the string is split; using `1` tells Python to only split on the first `:` character, leaving any others in place.
- use a regular expression:

  ```
  import re

  name, value = re.split(r'\s+:\s+', line, 1)
  value = value.rstrip()  # remove a remaining newline
  ```

  Again, the `1` limits the number of times the split is applied.

Comment: Thank you!

as I am new to python I haven't figured out how to get it to work as I would like to.

If I use
'name, value = line.split(':', 1)'
'name, value = name.strip(), value.strip()'

and call _name_ and _value_ I get
'Light Value' and '15.6'.

This looks just like I want it. However, I cannot figure out how to call the rest of the _members_, e.g. GPS Pitch, File Name etcetera.

Would you be able to help me?

Comment: @Minary just store everything in dictionaries like you were already doing? You had most of your code working already after all.

Comment: Cheers! I will have a look at that tomorrow. Even though I (almost) got it working as I want with ExifTool I would like to learn how to do it using Python.

Regards
Joel

Comment: Haven't had time to look at it properly. As I could use ExifTool to make progress I found new problems to work on so... Anyhow, thank you for you help. I will try to have a closer look at this in the future as I would like t be able to do this in Python as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question -- but I've seen multiple responders mention the `-T` flag for tab-delimited output, but none have mentioned the `-csv` option.

Running:

```
$ exiftool -a -csv -u -g1 my-picture.jpg
```

Will print all available tags and their values in CSV format, which is extremely convenient for parsing; you can use the [built-in CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or even something heavier like Pandas.

See the 'input-output text formatting' section of the wiki: https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html